# Using Knockout with an HTML button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm using knockout in the following manner successfully:

```
<div id="Options" data-bind="foreach: Options">

        <button type="button" data-bind="css: { selected: IsSelected }, enable: $parent.allow, click: $parent.select"><img src="/path/to/img.png"/></button>

    </div>
```

Now, I'm trying to change the buttons into images with the following:

```
<div id="Options" data-bind="foreach: Options">

        <input type="image" data-bind="css: { selected: IsSelected }, attr:{src:/path/to/img.png}, enable: $parent.allow, click: $parent.select" />

    </div>
```

My goal is to pair every Option to its own image using knockout.

The buttons aren't loading with the second option, so I'm thinking the syntax is off.  Any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're setting the image source is wrong. You're trying to set it to the value of a string but you need to write it in as a string literal (i.e., with quotes).  The reason you're able to set the bindings without them in the other bindings is because they are properties of your view model.

Either of these should work:

```
<input type="image" data-bind="css: { selected: IsSelected }, attr:{src:'/path/to/img.png'}, enable: $parent.allow, click: $parent.select" />

<input type="image" src="/path/to/img.png" data-bind="css: { selected: IsSelected }, enable: $parent.allow, click: $parent.select" />
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm trying to use the first one because each button will have a different image (corresponding to the option) - however the buttons still aren't showing up even with the single quotes.  Your second version works just fine.

Comment: That should have worked. Were there any errors in the console? What are you binding the `src` to?

Comment: Ah, I was missing a bracket.  Thanks Jeff :)